# Replace webpage with Firefox Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web-extension

I'm trying to make a Firefox extension that sends you to a webpage when an offending word is found in the document title. I already have a webpage that I want to send them to, but `document.location.href` doesn't work. How do I do this using a Content Script?

I have tried `document.location.href` and that didn't work. No search results were helpful.

Comment: I think that this thread should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/22486239

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.